# MathJax - \bbox alignment issues

Tags: horizontal-alignment, mathjax

I'm working on a post using mostly markdown but for the math side of things I've thrown MathJax in, I've been trying to get a definition for rings inside of a box and I've discovered as per the MathJax documentation that `\bbox` is the way to do this, however, the alignment is not how I'd like it to be. As you can see, I'm trying to do multi-line in the text box and have the formulas sat below and on the left of the sentence beginning "The set" but this seems to be borderline impossible. (See below.)

[image: MathJax poor rendering]

As you can see, the alignment is very messed up. I've tried to remedy this using `\begin{multline}`, `\\` and then now with `\begin{align}` but I really cannot seem to get this working or get any kind of decent alignment at all. Please see below for what this looks like in terms of the actual TeX.

```
$$ \bbox[5px, border:2px solid black]
{
\begin{align}
\text{The set} \; \mathbb{Z}_m = \{0, 1, 2, ..., m-1\} \; \text{Two Operations "+" and} \ "\cdot" \text{for all} \; a, b, c, d ∈ \mathbb{Z}_m \; \text{such that:} \\
a + b &\equiv d \; \bmod \; \\
a \cdot b &\equiv c \; \bmod \; m 
\end{align}
}
$$
```

Please forgive me if this post lacks details, correct structure or form, and comment if you require anything else!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. MathJax is off topic here.

Comment: @Johannes_B Hey! Okay, do you know where I can ask then? And, maybe you don't need a tag at all if that's the case? Perhaps a little bit misleading. Thanks for informing me though.

Comment: Although above post uses MathJax, the code executes similarly using just TeX, except that you need to strip off the formatting part behind `\bbox` of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question is about LaTeX code (and not about the *mathjax* `\bbox` command), it seems to be in topic.

Consider this LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& \text{The set} \; \mathbb{Z}_m = \{0, 1, 2, ..., m-1\} \; \text{Two Operations "+" and "} \cdot\text{" for all} \; a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}_m \; \text{such that:} \\
& a + b \equiv d \; \bmod \\
& a \cdot b \equiv c \; \bmod \; m 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

(I have replaced "∈" from your original code by "\in")

You obtain :
[image]

So, with this *mathjax* code:

```
$$ \bbox[5px, border:2px solid black]
{
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& \text{The set} \; \mathbb{Z}_m = \{0, 1, 2, ..., m-1\} \; \text{Two Operations "+" and "} \cdot\text{" for all} \; a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}_m \; \text{such that:} \\
& a + b \equiv d \; \bmod \\
& a \cdot b \equiv c \; \bmod \; m 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
}
$$
```

you have:
[image]

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you, very, very much! (This comment will probably get deleted)